# Selenium login to page with python 3.6 can't find element by name

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, python-3.6

Today I tried to write a code to make a bot for ytpals.com webpage.
I am using python selenium library. 
What I am trying to do first is to login to page with my youtube channel ID.
But I was unsucessfull to find element 'channelid' whatever I do.
Adding to this this, page sometimes doesn't load fully...

Btw it worked for me with other pages to find an input form, but this page... I can't understand.
Maybe someone has better understanding than me and know how to log in in this page?

My simple code:

```html
import time
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://www.ytpals.com/')

search = browser.find_element_by_name('channelid')
search.send_keys("testchannel")
time.sleep(5) # sleep for 5 seconds so you can see the results
browser.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

So I found a solution to my problem.
I downloaded SELENIUM IDE, and I can use it as a debugger, such a great tool!
if someone will need it, grab a link:
https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.jsp